# request.GetFile cannot get UTF-8 charset content

Tags: grails

I am getting an error when uploading a file with UTF-8 characters as `multipart/form-data` in Grails.

I am using the Form below;

```
<form action="uploadPost" enctype="multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8" method="POST">
    <label class="form-titles" for="csvList">Choose a file: </label>
<input type="file" id="csvList" name="csvList" style="width: 200px;"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
```

In the controller I have:

```
def file = request.getFile('csvList')
```

This causes the error:

> ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver] - No signature of method: org.springframework.security.wrapper.SavedRequestAwareWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [userList]
>   Possible solutions: getXML(), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getLocale(), getJSON()>

I think this will be same in Java.

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to get UTF-8 charset in multipart form?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Full stacktrace --- groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.security.wrapper.SavedRequestAwareWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [userList]
Possible solutions: getXML(), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getLocale(), getJSON()

 at UserController$_closure14.doCall(UserController:284)

 at UserController$_closure14.doCall(UserController)

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Answer (score 0):

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Don't put a charset in the "enctype" attribute.

Comment: and run with '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' parameter

Comment: Only multipart/form-data cannot get utf-8 characters such as accented character 'Kübler' from the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you declared the `utf8` inside the `enctype` and the server didn't understand as a multipart. Try:

```
<form method="post" action="uploadPost" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thank you, Sérgio! Your answer helped me get passed the Grails error. I also found that the file that is uploaded should be UTF-8 encoded. Everything worked as expected after that.